# how to get the Output expectations?

Tags: python, data-structures

> ## TODO: 4. Correct the following function so that you can calculate the rank of all Dictionary elements

```
dict_number = {
    1:1,
    2:2,
    3:3,
}

def calculate_the_rank_of_the_dictionary(dictionaryKu):
    for i in dictionaryKu:
        # Complete this code
    return dictionaryKu

print(calculate_the_rank_of_the_dictionary(dict_number)) # Output expectations: {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9}
```

Comment: `print({k: v*v for k, v in dict_number.items()})`

Comment: Hi! It seems that you and a few fellow students got some new homework and posted a few questions each from the same problem set. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60972796/1723886) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60973448/1723886). Do note that it is OK to post homework questions. But you need to show that you have put some effort into it. There is a good [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which more info on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
dict_number = {
    1:1,
    2:2,
    3:3,
}

def calculate_the_rank_of_the_dictionary(dictionaryKu):
    for i in dictionaryKu:
        dictionaryKu[i] = i**2
    return dictionaryKu

print(calculate_the_rank_of_the_dictionary(dict_number))
```