# what the code to use in # Complete this function with recursion in lines 4

Tags: python

```
# TODO: 2. Create a function that counts the sum of all the numbers in a list below

number = [1,2,3,4,5] # Use this list as input

def hitung_total(listKu):
    # Complete this function with recursion
    return listKu
```

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code-for-hire site. If you have a specific issue, show us what you've tried to do.

Comment: Please change your title to reflect what your actual question is. The point is ot be beneficial for future users not just yourself.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973448/what-function-recursion-to-complete-in-lines-4 with the exact same homework wording.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up all the numbers in the list you could do something like this:

```py
number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

result = sum(number)
```